# catalog_product_import_finish_before Event in magento2?

Tags: event-observer, magento2.2, php-7

Created an observer file in Magento1, using event

> catalog_product_import_finish_before

event

```
     $productIds = array();
            $adapter = $observer->getEvent()->getAdapter();
          $resource = $this->_stockCollection;

          if ($adapter instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product) {
            $productIds = $adapter->getAffectedEntityIds(); 
            $this->_logger->info(print_r($productIds),true);
       } else {
         Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import::getDataSourceModel()->getIterator()->rewind();
           $skus = array();
           while ($bunch = $adapter->getNextBunch()) {
              foreach ($bunch as $rowData) {
                   if (null !== $rowData['sku']) {
                   $skus[] = $rowData['sku'];
                }
              }
         }
           if (!empty($skus)) {
              $productIds = $resource->getProductsIdBySku($skus);
         }
```

How to get this Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product file and AffectedEntityIds in Magento2?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 have same event name

> app/code/Magento/CatalogImportExport/Model/Import/Product.php

**`catalog_product_import_finish_before`**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('catalog_product_import_finish_before', ['adapter' => $this]);
```

You can use

```
 $adapter = $observer->getEvent()->getAdapter();
 $Entityids = $adapter->getAffectedEntityIds();
```

Comment: But i can't get the $Entityids ...@Patel

Answer (score 0):

`\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product::getAffectedEntityIds()` method is obsolete in Magento 2 - it does not exist anymore.

What you could do to get affected entity ids for 'Add/Replace' strategy is `catalog_product_import_bunch_save_after` which gives you access to `$bunch`, and `$this` (adapter).

To obtain ids in a custom observer, something like this could be done:

```
    /** @var array $bunch */
    $bunch = $observer->getEvent()->getBunch();

    /** @var Product $adapter */
    $adapter = $observer->getEvent()->getAdapter();

    foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
        $productData = $adapter->getNewSku($rowData[Product::COL_SKU]);
        $productId = $productData['entity_id']);
        if (!isset($productData['entity_id'])) {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Other strategies have separate events like `catalog_product_import_bunch_delete_after`